# How to stop the execution successive one if preceding one fails when commands are written in line by line by using && operator

Tags: bash, shell, centos7

I have some commands for installing in shell script.I am Using && for stopping the execution of successive one if the preceding command fails.
for eg:

```
yum -y install httpd && yum -y install ntp && yum -y install XYZ && yum -y install libxml2-devel.
```

The execution stops at XYZ because XYZ is not the valid command.

But the problem is when these are written in line by line the && function is not working.

```
yum -y install httpd &&
yum -y install ntp &&
yum -y install XYZ && 
yum -y install libxml2-devel &&
```

when the commands are written in this way all libxml2-devel is also executing even XYZ fails. 
Any mistake am i doing.?
Please Help.

How to stop the execution successive one if preceding one fails when commands are written in line by line by using && operator.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the last `&&`; `&&` is a logical operator that joins two commands conditionally, depending on exit status -- the second one will only be run if the first one succeeds (exits with status 0).

You have not used any command after the last `&&`, so you would get the unexpected end of file error. So, drop the last `&&` (or add something after that):

```
yum -y install httpd &&
yum -y install ntp &&
yum -y install XYZ && 
yum -y install libxml2-devel
```

Comment: Then i am getting like this available.libxml2-devel
Error: Nothing to do

Comment: @prasanna Thats a totally different error....ask a new question regarding that please...

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. Then I am getting like this.                     
 Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 available.libxml2-devel
Error: Nothing to do.                                                                               
But I don't want this. when i execute in a single line The above erroe didn't happen.